# Caliburn.Micro disable default click event for ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, caliburn.micro

I have a ViewModel which inherits from `Conductor<T>.Collection.OneActive`. In the View I bound a `DataGrid` to the `Items` property and a `ContentControl` to `ActiveItem`.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="Items" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
              cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action test]">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CountryCode}" Width="10*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Country}" Width="90*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</ContentControl>
```

It's working fine, except one thing: I want to activate the `DetailsViewModel` when one of the Grid's row was DoubleClicked. My `void test()` method gets invoked nicely, but I can not disable the Click method.

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

Maybe i was not clear enough. My problem is the default behavior of the `Conductor<T>`. It should not activate the details screen for one left click but for double.

**EDIT 2**

By `Nkosi`'s help finally figured out some workaround:
Simply changed ContentControl binding from `ActiveItem` to `ActiveScreen`.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveScreen" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
```

In the ViewModel created the `ActiveScreen` property:

```
private T mActiveScreen;
public T ActiveScreen
{
    get { return mActiveScreen; }
    set
    {
        mActiveScreen = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ActiveScreen);
    }
}
```

In the bound method for `MouseDoubleClick` you just have to set `ActiveScreen` to `ActiveItem`.

```
    public void test()
    {
        ActiveScreen = ActiveItem;
    }
```

Comment: It activates because once you select on item it becomes the ActiveItem which would activate it. Even if you clicked on one item and then used the arrow keys up and down it would activate every selected item.

Comment: I see, but how can i turn off this behavior?

Comment: Maybe it's activate items when selection change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caliburn has an action guard feature where `Can{MethodName}` acts as a guard for the action to be invoked. It can be either a property or another method, once it follows the convention.

So given

```
public void test() { ... }
```

its guard would look like

```
public bool Cantest {
    get { return //..what ever is the condition needed to allow/disable action
}
```

or

```
public bool Cantest() {
    return //..what ever is the condition needed to allow/disable action
}
```

[Caliburn documentation - All About Actions](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions)

> Another important feature to note is Action guards. When a handler is
>   found for the “SayHello” message, it will check to see if that class
>   also has either a property or a method named “CanSayHello.” If you
>   have a guard property and your class implements
>   INotifyPropertyChanged, then the framework will observe changes in
>   that property and re-evaluate the guard accordingly.

Comment: I updated my question, because we had some missunderstand, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

In Caliburn.Micro EventAggregator concept is thier. Read that concept that will help you

Publish the message in current viewmodel and subscribe in DetailsViewModel.
Its works.

https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator

and 
[Caliburn.Micro EventAggregator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335663/caliburn-micro-eventaggregator)

Comment: I think i understand the way EventAggregator works, but can not figure out how should this help me in this specific situation. Could you please explain in more detail? I also updated my question.

Comment: Yeah, you applied event for data grid where ever you clicked inside datagrid that event triggered, that fine. Now u should create button(Close) and inside button publish a  msg to Home Viewmodel  and in home View model active the Home Screen.

Comment: If its not working send detail issue to my mail. raghavaarr559@gmail.com